# How can I get Emacs to launch new frame when a file is dropped onto the Dock icon?

Tags: osx, emacs-mac-port

I have Emacs installed with `brew install emacs-mac --HEAD --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-librsvg --with-imagemagick`. I have the final `.app` binary in the OS X Dock.

If I drag a file onto the Dock icon, the default behavior opens it in the last-activated frame, even if it is on a different desktop. I'd like files to open in a new frame in the current desktop when drag-and-dropped onto the icon. Is this behavior possible? Yes, because this is emacs. Can anyone suggest a place to begin implementing this?

Comment: I don't use the Brew or dropping stuff in Dock icons, but I have looked into altering `ns-find-file` so that files opened from the **Finder.app** get displayed in certain select frames (using a custom function and let-binding the `display-buffer-alist`).  Why not try adding a message to `ns-find-file` and drop your file on the Dock and see if the message gets displayed?  If it does, then "Bingo!".  If not, then "Go Fish!".  Here is a link to a modified version of `ns-find-file`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until someone suggest a better implementation, I over-write `dnd-open-local-file` to open in a new frame instead of a new window:

```
(setq dnd-open-file-other-frame t)    
(defun dnd-open-local-file (uri _action)
  (let* ((f (dnd-get-local-file-name uri t)))
    (if (and f (file-readable-p f))
    (progn
      (if dnd-open-file-other-frame
          (find-file-other-frame f)
        (find-file f))
      'private)
      (error "Can not read %s" uri))))
```